# How NOT to overwrite the .mat file when using scipy.io.savemat()?

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, append

I have been using Python's `scipy.io.savemat()` to save my data in .mat format, efficient way to transfer data between the two: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.9.0/reference/tutorial/io.html.

Somehow it overwrite the file. How to set the function so I can append to the .mat file instead of overwriting just like MATLAB save()'s  '-append' option? Or is there any ways to work it out other than scipy.io.savemat()?

Answer (score 3):

There doesn't appear to be a way to append with `scipy.io.savemat()`.

You can `scipy.io.loadmat()`, append your new values to the dict that is returned, and then call `scipy.io.savemat()` again.

Here is the documentation for `scipy.io.loadmat()`:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html

Comment: It't not as easy as it may appear, according to the associated ticket: [savemat() append to file #2967](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/2967)

Comment: for simple file content, `savemat` works with a file that has been opened in append mode.  The problems arise when the `.mat` contains MATLAB functions.

Comment: Thank you both for clearing the problem, seems we have to stick to it currently.

Comment: Another reason to get rid of the old mat format and use hdf5 instead. Since version 7.3 mat files can be gzip compressed hdf5 files.

Comment: hi @hpaulj , what does it means concerning `.mat contans matlab functions`?

Comment: MATLAB can save many things to a `.mat` file, structures, cells, matrices, and functions (maybe classes as well).  But MATLAB functions aren't of any use in `numpy`.  So `loadmat/savemat` aren't set up to handle them.  And of course Python functions can't be saved to .mat either.