# How to append to .mat file using scipy.io.savemat?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

so when I use the savemat command it tends to overwrite the file. Is there a possible way to append instead of overwriting? I know a work-around would be to put everything into a list, and then convert it to a dictionary. That won't work for me because I am trying to be RAM efficient. Doing online search I found this [How NOT to overwrite the .mat file when using scipy.io.savemat()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26963446/how-not-to-overwrite-the-mat-file-when-using-scipy-io-savemat)

that won't work either because it involves pulling a data file in your ram memory to append it every single loop, which seems stupid from the speed perspective.

I thought about appending to a numpy binary file, then pulling that in and saving it to a .mat file? I am not sure if this would be more RAM efficient than the first option though.

thanks!

Comment: Are adding a new variable to the file, or adding values to existing variables?  And what's with this 'every single loop'?  Are you trying to write data to the file incrementally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to `savemat` docs:

> file_name : str or file-like object

So you can open the file in append mode, and write, e.g.

```
io.savemat('temp.mat',{'data':np.ones(10)})  # write
with open('temp.mat','ab') as f:
    io.savemat(f, {'newdata':np.arange(5)})   # append
print io.loadmat('temp.mat').keys()           # read
# dict_keys(['data', '__globals__', 'newdata', '__header__', '__version__'])
```

Or the full description:

```
{'data': array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]]),
 '__globals__': [],
 'newdata': array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]),
 '__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file Platform: posix, Created on: Fri Mar 13 14:14:33 2015',
 '__version__': '1.0'}
```

A note in https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/io/matlab/mio5.py#L34 suggests that there is a problem with appending when there's a function in the data file, but this indicates that appending isn't a problem if we are just saving arrays.  But maybe further search of the `scipy` issues is in order.

Comment: It creates the file but for some reason I can't load it.

I get a TypeError: Expecting miINT32 as data type. You can append data to the same dictionary key. But you can't append new dictionary keys with new data and that's what I want to do. I will mark it as answer because it answers my question but does not solve my problem

Comment: I was basically able to use the suggested method.  However, if a particular variable name already exists in the file, then the file becomes unreadable.

Comment: yeah I did a test and when there are multiple of the same keys, you get that `TypeError: Expecting miINT32 ` error

Comment: The example in the solution here works fine. When I use it on my own numpy array, I get `ValueError: Did not read any bytes` when trying to read (after saving)

Answer (score 1):

It only works for one append!If you append twice, Matlab gives an error "File might be currupt".

```
scipy.io.savemat('temp.mat',{'data':np.ones(10)})  # write
with open('temp.mat','ab') as f:
    scipy.io.savemat(f, {'newdata1':np.arange(5)})   # append
with open('temp.mat','ab') as f:
   scipy.io.savemat(f, {'newdata2':np.arange(5)})   # append
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option if you need to append huge data is the next:

```
self.upload1 = sio.loadmat(self.namedir,self.params)
sio.savemat('params_lo.mat', self.upload1)
```

With this form you load the data and add the new variables. Be careful because if they have the same name it doesn't change its values. So in order to correct this I delete all the variables that I want to change.

```
    self.upload = sio.loadmat(self.namedir)
    for i in self.str_vars:
       try:
          del self.upload[i]
       except:
          continue
    sio.savemat('params_lo.mat', self.upload)
    self.upload1 = sio.loadmat(self.namedir,self.params)
    sio.savemat('params_lo.mat', self.upload1)
```