# How to save multiple data sets with the sio.savemat function?

Tags: python, matlab, loops, scipy, save

I have created a code in python that reads multiple files (reads specific parts of them) and my goal is to save all these data points to matlab format. This is my 'main program' (all the functions are defined before):

Comment: The normal action of most `save` functions is to write to a new file, overwriting any file of the same name.  Some User Friendly commands ask if you want to overwrite.  Otherwise you have to take special actions to open a file for `appending`.  And as the answer found there are limits to what can be appended to a complex data structure like a `.mat`.

Answer (score 2):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29040276/how-to-append-to-mat-file-using-scipy-io-savemat) is about how to append data using savemat. It looks like that asker says you can only append data to the existing dictionary key though, so it may not solve your problem.

What I recommend is adding the data to a dictionary and then saving it all to a mat file once, at the end.

Initialize a dictionary outside the loop

```
myDictionary = {}
```

You have one line of code that creates the dictionary and saves it.

```
sio.savemat('Argo_Trajectories.mat', {'data':data})
```

Replace that line with two: create a unique key rather than naming them all data and add the data to the dictionary

```
newkey = 'data%d' % ifl
myDictionary[newkey] = data
```

After the loop is finished, save the dictionary (this can be before or after the 2nd `print(z)` in your function

```
sio.savemat('savename.mat',myDictionary)
```

Comment: First if all, thanks for answering! It sounds like it'll work, and I'm going to try this, but I have a question before I do. I will edit my question and add my data processing function, because I am not entirely sure where you want me to put the second and third commands you posted. Should I insert them into the loop, or into the function (which I'll post in a moment)? Thanks again