# Python savemat only saves the last image feature

Tags: python, matlab, file, scipy, mat

I wrote a code to save image features to .mat files in python. However, although I added 'append' section in savemat function, it only saves the last image feature in .mat file. How can I save all image features (for example if I have 5 images, I will have 5 x 512 size .mat file)

```
  pics = {}
  for file in os.listdir(input_path):
    filename = os.fsdecode(file)
    img = Image.open(os.path.join(input_path, filename))
    vec = img2vec.get_vec(img)
    print(len(vec))   
    pics[filename] = vec
    io.savemat('final.mat',{"foo":vec},'-append')
```

Comment: I don't see anything the `savemat` docs about a '-append' parameter.  And your indent doesn't look right.  I think you should accumulate all images, and save with just one call to `savemat`.

Comment: Have you taken a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29040276/how-to-append-to-mat-file-using-scipy-io-savemat ?
The '-append' parameter seems to come from the save function of MATLAB : https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html

Comment: The kind of append I tested in that link can only add new variables.  It cannot add to a saved one.